# antlr4 syntax error "complete surprise to me while matching alternative"

Tags: antlr4

I have grammar as follows.
antlr4 gives error for this grammar.
Please help me to resolve this error

Thank you very much.

---

```
grammar test_grammar;

addressSpaceIdentifier : '_readonly'
| '_kernarg'
;

optaddressSpace : [addressSpaceIdentifier]
;
```

---

Error:
error(50): C:\test\test_grammar1.g:12:18: syntax error: 'addressSpaceIden
tifier' came as a complete surprise to me while matching alternative

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
optaddressSpace : [addressSpaceIdentifier]
;
```

is invalid. If you meant to make the production `addressSpaceIdentifier` optional, you need to write it like this:

```
optaddressSpace : addressSpaceIdentifier?
;
```